# Error Highlighting and Intellisense Not Working for JavaScript file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Error highlighting and intellisense not working for `.js` file but `.ts` in VSCode version 1.18.1

[image: JavaScript file]
[image: TypeScript file]

Comment: have you setup a linter for js?

Comment: No, I have not setup linter.     I think it should support out of the box that intellisence and error highlights